# JAX-WS and JAX-RS service class instantiation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, jax-ws

Is it specified somewhere in these API
whether an instance of a `MyService` class is used
to serve many requests or a different instance is created on a per request basis ?

By what I've experimented It looks like that:

- Frameworks implementing `JAX-WS`, instantate a new instance for
  each SOAP request.
- Meanwhile frameworks implementing `JAX-RS`, use the same instance to
  serve different requests.

Also, in some cases I guess it is important to know whether a framework is allowed to
unload a service class to free space, does these specifications say something about that ?

thanks.

Comment: Don't know about JAX-WS, but with JAX-RS, it configurable. Your assumption about the same instance is incorrect. Default is actually per request

Comment: How can I configure this ?

Comment: Depends. Any type of scanning for resources will automatically make them per request. If you register an instance it will be a singleton. Some implementaions will allow @Singleton to make it a singleton

Comment: The default behaviour for JAX-WS is a stateless, threadsafe execution chain (for the webservice at least). There are constructs to implement stateful jax-ws services, but that's when you go out of your way to implement that. You could also defeat the per-request default behaviour, by, say, adding a `static` class-level variable to your service implementation bean

Comment: Do you have examples of what you've tried? JAX-RS tends to lean on the CDI spec to control instantiation, allowing users to create singletons in their application classes.  JAX-WS leans on EJB a bit declaring that they should be SLSBs, or you can define as a singleton in most cases.